# ¿Como prolongar la ejecución de un evento en un input?

Tags: angular, angular5, buscador, angular6

Quizás este mal el titulo, pero acá me explicare mejor.

Tengo una tabla con datos traídos de una base de datos, esta tiene un input el cual se encarga de buscar según lo que se escriba allí.

Quisiera que cada vez que se escriba en el campo no se ejecute el evento ***keyup*** al instante sino que espere unos 2 o 3 segundos que el usuario pare de escribir.

```html
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="categorias.nombre" (keyup)="filterCampoEvent($event)">
```

En javascript lo hacia de la siguiente manera:

```
delay(function(){
    table.draw();
    e.preventDefault();
}, 1000 );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RxJs que viene incluido con Angular tiene una solución bastante elegante y sencilla para este caso de uso en especifico. En primer lugar asegúrate de incluir 
`ReactiveFormsModule` en tu módulo.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [...,ReactiveFormsModule ],
  declarations:[TuComponente]
})
export class TuModule { }
```

Luego en el componente que contiene tu input creas un objeto de tipo FormControl.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { debounceTime, distinctUntilChange } from 'rxjs/operators'
@Component({
   selector: 'app-tu-componente',
   templateUrl: './name-editor.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./name-editor.component.css']
})
export class TuComponent implements OnInit {
   nombre = new FormControl('');
   ngOnInit(){}
}
```

finalmente en tu HTML

```
<input type="text" [formControl]="nombre">
```

Ahora, los resultados de tu campo de texto hacen parte de un concepto denominado Observable. Un observable es un stream de datos que "emite" un valor cada vez que sucede un cambio, en este caso cada vez que el usuario escribe algo en tu campo de texto. La ventaja de los observables en este caso es que tu puedes "operar" sobre los resultados de múltiples formas. Puedes filtrar, cambiar un valor por otro, unirte a otro observable, etc.

En tu caso especifico, puedes ponerlo a esperar n milisegundos antes de realizar una acción contra el servidor. 
Para obtener el valor tienes que suscribirte al observable llamando a la función subscribe y pasandole una función que recibe el valor y realiza una acción, puedes hacerlo desde el hook OnInit

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.nombre.valueChanges.pipe( // La función pipe recibe operadores de RxJs que se ejecutan en orden
        debounceTime(1000), // Espera 1 segundo antes de emitir el valor del input
        distinctUntilChanged() // Evita que se emita el valor si es igual al ultimo valor que se emitió
    ).subscribe(val=>{
        llamarAlBackend(val)
    })
}
```

incluso si tu llamada al backend retorna los resultados como un observable puedes usar el operador `switchMap` para cancelar la llamada al backend y realizar una llamada nueva si el usuario tecleo algo mientras la petición se estaba resolviendo. Esto es útil para evitar que los resultados de la tabla muestren información en desorden si una petición se resolvió antes que otra.

Finalmente si no deseas usar el módulo de formularios reactivos (aunque no veo razón para hacerlo porque es una de las mejores características de Angular), puedes crear un observable con todos los keyup del input y realizar el mismo proceso de antes.

```
nombres$ = new Subject(); // el $ al final es simplemente una convención para denotar un observable.
```

y en tu HTML

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="categorias.nombre" (keyup)="nombres$.next($event)">
```

y en tu ngOnInit simplemente

```
ngOnInit(){
   this.nombres$.pipe( // Puedes incluir el resto del pipe sin ningún cambio.
}
```

Saludos!

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, intentando usar el primer modo me da error las funciones **debounceTime(1000)** y **distinctUntilChanged()**.

Comment: Hay que importar **import { debounceTime } from 'rxjs/operators/debounceTime';**. Modifica la respuesta para un futuro usuario.

Comment: Listo, edite la respuesta para que incluya los imports!

Answer (score 0):

Para eso vas a necesitar usar dos eventos y una variable global. Cuando se ejecute la primera vez, pasará por ambos y se ejecutará la función *filterCampoEvent*, ahí supongo que haras una función asincrona, dentro de ella pon la varible global a true y cuando se pase por el callback de success pon la variable global a false y funcionará.

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="categorias.nombre" (keyup)="onKeyUp(this)" (keydown)="onKeyDown(this)">

isWaiting = true; //Declarado como false

function onKeyUp(input) {
    if(! isWaiting){
    event.preventDefault();
    return;
  }
  filterCampoEvent();
}

function onKeyDown(input) {
  //Entra primero aqui
  event.preventDefault();
    if(isWaiting){
    input.reset;
  }
}
```

Saludos!!

Comment: No funciona hermano.

Comment: Puedes poner mas información de la clase que usas en angular y la función que llamas?